# Understanding a template to modify it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't seem to understand the Russian Doll philosophy of html and thus, I fail to correctly apply css to the desired container.

Here are two templates I'd like to use simultaneously :

- http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/index5.html
- http://tympanus.net/Development/SectionSeparators/

And my problem is that the result is this :

First everything seems all right :
[image]
Then I click on the hamburger to open the menu :
[image]
The problem is that the portion of code which does the border the overlay applies on `<nav>` and it doesn't seem to affect the `<section>` but it does affecter the `<header>` and `<footer>` (you can't see the later on the screenshots).

Here is the portion of code :

```
 .bt-menu.bt-menu-open {
         height: 100%;
         border-width: 30px 30px 30px 90px;
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
         transition: border-width 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
 }
```

I reached this conclusion by doing this :
[image]
And also adding the above css to my sections inline. It did what I would expect by opening the menu.

**So, why doesn't it affect my section?**

Here is my html if it can prove useful : http://pastebin.com/g7Exx64f

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to go through. At least make a snippet on here or post a [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/) so we can be more of a help.

Comment: The two templates I'm using are nicely documented, I was hoping it would suffice. I'll make that.
I found one for the section separator : http://codepen.io/lukeyphills/pen/FjygE

Comment: `I was hoping it would suffice.` StackOverflow is not a code dump site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#89d761c4072d7ae653f1a8205392074a

I skimmed through the CSS from the [pen](http://codepen.io/lukeyphills/pen/FjygE) you linked some have a z-index which means it's stacked above your element.

Plus your container is probably not set to `position: fixed;` so your content will scroll with you.

In addition you can toggle the display of the social network icons in pure css. You will need an `input[type=checkbox]` with a unique id. Say `#callmenu`. Then you need a `label[for=callmenu]`. For is used trigger the checkbox when clicked.

Say you want to toggle the display of `.social`. To do this with the checkbox you set what you want the css of .social to be before it's checked.

```
.social {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then you set what you want it to look like when the checkbox is checked...

```
#callmenu:checked ~ .social {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The snippet below is a simple example of what I believe you'd like to achieve.

You can view [this weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#89d761c4072d7ae653f1a8205392074a) which utilizes the [pen](http://codepen.io/lukeyphills/pen/FjygE) you linked and [font-awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

```css
/* Border Menu */
#callmenu {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
label[for=callmenu] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 2.6752em;
  margin: 0.2em 0.7488em;
  color: #666;
}
.bgoverlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: 1;
}
.icon-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #3a3a3a;
  z-index: 1;
}
.icon-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2.576em 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-menu li {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.icon-menu li a {
  color: #999;
  padding: 1.12em;
  transition: all ease-in 150ms;
}
.icon-menu li a:hover {
  color: #cecece;
}

/* When menu is checked */
#callmenu:checked ~ .icon-menu li {
  font-size: 1.76em;
  margin: 0.768em 0;
}
#callmenu:checked ~ label[for=callmenu] {
  color: #d5ebe4;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="callmenu">
<div class="bgoverlay"></div>
<div class="icon-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        Twitter
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        G+
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        Facebook
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<label for="callmenu">
  menu
</label>
```

Comment: Definitely what I wanted to do. But I don't understand quite well "Plus your container is probably not set to position: fixed; ". The menu does scroll with me but it disappears when it goes through the sections (and reappear at some junctions and at the footer).
Anyway I have everything I need in my hand, I'll try to understand everything.

Comment: That is because of `z-index`

Comment: Sigh, I added z-index = 1000; (hight than the sections thus) and it solved everything : http://codepen.io/LittleNooby/pen/eZjqaP